# Java regex issue with: ###tag1@@@value1###tag2@@@value2###tag3@@@value3###

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble writing a regex to validate the following pattern:

```
###tag1@@@value1###tag2@@@value2###tag3@@@value3###
```

- This can repeat indefinitely
- The tags and values can contain any printable char as well as whitespace and newlines

I've been trying variations of this:

```
String pattern = "(###[\\p{Print}\\s]+@@@[\\p{Print}\\s]+)+###"
```

But it is not enforcing the pattern for certain cases such as:

```
###testTag@@@testValue###testtag2testvalue2### (missing the @@@ for tag2/value2)
```

And its invalidating some **valid inputs** such as:

```
###component@@@CORE COMMAND GROUP###severity@@@DEBUG###message@@@Validating potential model load directory: C:/some/dir/market-xxxxxx/market-xxxxxx-PRODUCT-kit/data/XXX_7020190724201513_0X###
```

Any suggestions on how I can improve this regex?  Thanks!

I'm using the Java pattern lib.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What part of the data do you want to extract?

Comment: Can `###` or `@@@` be part of tag or value?

Comment: So would `testtag2testvalue2` be considered the tag or the value? Arbitrarily missing the `@@@` is not something that regex is going to split for you automagically...

Comment: @anubhava No the expectation is that @@@ and ### are delimiters and not part of the tags or values.  Otherwise it would be impossible to enforce.  However, ## @@ # and @ are ok.

Comment: Are you sure all your characters you expect to printable are printable indeed?

Comment: @Imaginary I'm extracting the key value pairs.  Eg... for ###tag1@@@value1### I want tag1=value1

Comment: @Monkey testtag2testvalue2 would be a single tag or value because there is no delimiter.   testTag@@@testValue###testtag2testvalue2### should be invalidated because there is not @@@ delimiter between the two ### delimeters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ma use this regex"

```
final String regex = 
 "^(?:###(?:(?!@@@|###)\\P{C})+@@@(?:(?!@@@|###)\\P{C})+)+###$";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGaASg/4)

- `\P{C}` matches any printable unicode character
- `(?:(?!@@@|###)\\P{C})` matches any printable unicode character if it is not immediately followed by `###` or `@@@`

Comment: This is not working, but I think you're on the right track.  It needs to see a # or @ and understand that it could be part of @@@ or ###

Comment: I didn't notice starting and ending `###` due to formatting issues earlier.

Comment: It's working.  I'm going to add a few more test cases to make sure and then I'll make this the correct answer.  Thank you!!

Comment: Worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: how would I add tabs and newlines in this regex.  Apparently they are not included in the printable char set

Comment: nevermind "^(?:###(?:(?!@@@|###)\\P{C}|\\s)+@@@(?:(?!@@@|###)\\P{C}|\\s)+)+###$" did it

Answer (score 1):

This works well :

```java
String s1 = "###tag1@@@value1###tag2@@@value2###tag3@@@value3###";
String s2 = "testTag@@@testValue###testtag2testvalue2###";
String s3 = "component@@@CORE COMMAND GROUP###severity@@@DEBUG###message@@@Validating potential model load directory: C:/some/dir/market-xxxxxx/market-xxxxxx-PRODUCT-kit/data/XXX_7020190724201513_0X###";

String p = "(###|^)?(((\P{C})+?@@@(\P{C})+?)###|$)+?";

Matcher m1 = p.matcher(s1); // testTag@@@testValue
Matcher m2 = p.matcher(s2); // tag1@@@value1, tag2@@@value2, tag3@@@value3
Matcher m3 = p.matcher(s3); // component@@@CORE COMMAND GROUP, severity@@@DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

This will almost get you there:

```
(###)((.+?)(@@@)(.+?)(###))
```

https://regex101.com/r/5rfpL0/4

I'm just having a hard time figuring out why:

```
(###)((.+?)(@@@)(.+?)(###))+
```

doesn't make it behave as expected :-/

Comment: Isn't it because its looking for ###tag@@@value### repeated?  So ###tag@@@value###tag2@@@value2### would fail because it would require ###tag@@@value######tag2@@@value2### (note the 6 # between the 2 pairs)